# How to navigate to local network?

Tags: networking, nautilus

In Nautilus (v3.2.1), in the left-hand navigation pane, there is an entry `Browse Network`. This is only available when the sidebar is set to `Places`.

I prefer the sidebar setting `Tree` but then the entry `Browse Network` disappears. I'm too much of a beginner to figure out where to look in the filesystem in order to find the networked computers (file shares on Windows 7).

**When not using the `Places` setting in the sidebar, how do I navigate to the network shares?**

Comment: `smb://[other-pc-ip-address]` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the menu at the top of the screen, you can choose *Go* -> *Network*.

[image]

You can also type the address in manually:

1. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>
2. Enter the location `network:///`
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: This brings me to the path `network:///` from which I can go into shares like `smb://other-pc/users/torben/`. I thought there was something like /media/... or /net/... or similar? I thought that in Linux, everything that is reachable is found somewhere in the filesystem. Am I mistaken?

Comment: `/media/` will take you to a folder with all of your mounted drives (which may include network locations?), but the `Browse Network` entry that you mentioned in your question goes to `network:///`.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun you may access like `smb://other-pc-ip-address` :)

Answer (score 2):

Make it a bookmark and switch to it by *Bookmarks -> Network*